# Angular material design toolbar - formatting problems

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a web-page where I use the md-toolbar from Angular material design, but I have some formatting problems. Here is the base code:

```
<md-toolbar style="position: fixed;">
<div class="md-toolbar-tools md-whiteframe-z1">

    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Top Toolbar" hide-gt-sm ng-click="vm.toggleSideNav()">
        <ng-md-icon icon="menu"></ng-md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <h2>
        <span>Top Toolbar</span>
    </h2>
    <span flex></span>
    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="vm.logout()" aria-label="Logout" show-gt-sm>
        Logout
    </md-button>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that if I remove the `style="position: fixed;"`from the md-toolbar the toolbar just takes up a small part of the width of the screen. When I added position: fixed it takes up the whole width of the screen, but the logout button doesn't show. It's like it's pushed out of the view of the screen. I haven't been able to figure out how I can both show the logout button and have the toolbar stretch across the whole page.

Here is the parent of the toolbar (minus all script inclusions etc):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="otpAdminApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

    <style type="text/css">
        [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController as vm" ng-cloak>

    <div ng-view flex></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `md-toolbar`'s parent have full width?

Comment: See my edit, I've added the parent of the toolbar. As far as I understand it has full width.

Comment: Have you tried adding `flex` to your `md-toolbar`? You might have to add `layout="column"` to your `ng-view` element first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem lies in the parent of the toolbar.

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as vm" ng-cloak>

<div ng-view flex></div>

</body>
```

You are using `div` element with `flex` and in this case div will only consume the space required by its children elements. Example. You can check this by yourself using `background-color` css property. 
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/aNgGZa

so you must use `layout-fill` with `div` or `md-content` as required. Here is the working example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/EKBLyp

```
<md-content layout="column" layout-fill style="background-color:pink"> // in parent controller as per your code
<md-toolbar>
  <div class="md-toolbar-tools md-whiteframe-z1">

    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Top Toolbar" hide-gt-sm ng-click="vm.toggleSideNav()">
      <ng-md-icon icon="menu"></ng-md-icon>
    </md-button>
    <h2>
    <span>BankID OTP Administration</span></h2>
    <span flex></span>
    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="click = 'click'" aria-label="Logout" show-gt-sm>
      Logou
    </md-button>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
<div flex>
  Text
</div>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot give you a good answer without having a look at your code. Can you please create a plunkr. ?
As a quick-fix, You can add style="width : 100vw" replacing position:fixed (not a great option due to support issues in older browsers).
If you can create a plunkr, I will be able to help you out.